# How to determine if a string is in alphabetical order

Tags: java

How do I determine if a prompt for input string is in alphabetical order by using the compareTo method?

The string will all be lowercase, contains 3 words, the length of the words does not matter.

Comment: Compare each letter of each word one at a time? What have you tried so far?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @newbieprogrammer This won't work.

Comment: @andreas why not?

Comment: Take the input ,store them in array.Then create a new array and copy the elements of first array to newly created array.Then use the sort() method on newly created array.Compare the elements of both array if its match it is alphabetical or else it is not.

Comment: `inputString` is the original array and that won't get changed. `stringArr` is a new variable that receives `split` and `sort`

Comment: @Rojo Because in the now deleted comment the author compared an array with a string with the strict equality operator (`===`) which will always be false. And for the non-strict `==` case it would have required an explicit `.join(" ")` call on the array otherwise the implicit call of `.join()` would have joined the elements with a `,`

Comment: But if `.join()` is used, you can still use `===`, right?

Comment: @Rojo Only (in this particular case) with `.join(" ")`. `.join()` without parameter concatenates with `,`

Comment: @Andreas Okay I understand now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.sort()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp) and [`.split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and [`.join()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

```
var string = "how are you";
var string2 = string.split(" ");
string2.sort();
console.log(string2 ); // are, how, you
string2 = string2.join(" ");
console.log (string2 === string); // false
```

`.split()` splits the string every time there is a space. `.sort()` sorts each word alphabetically. `.join()` puts the string back together

Comment: @blex thanks for the split and sort syntax. But from what I understand, he has already made the words lowercase.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad. It would work still either way.

Comment: I dont think I'm allowed to use these methods. The string is a prompt

Comment: @Jack What do you mean by a prompt?

Comment: I just notice I accidentally put the tag as java script, this is for java. Prompt means JOptionPane.showInputDialog